# Vertical Center with Flexbox and alignment of child items

Tags: css, flexbox

Only getting around to trying out flexbox now and I'm using it to vertically center content inside a div.

```css
    .parent{
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <p>Paragraph one.</p>
       <p>Paragraph two.</p>
    </div>
```

So when I do this it works but the child elements are placed beside each other like they're not block items anymore. How can I have it that they're vertically centered but stacked on top of each other?

Cheers!

Comment: Go read up on `flex-direction` …

Comment: @04FS Thanks, flex-direction: column; does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show elements in column you need to use `flex-direction: column` style property.

```css
.parent{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <p>Paragraph one.</p>
   <p>Paragraph two.</p>
</div>
```